# PHP PDO INPUT SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am very new to working with Data Bases, I have researched this for several days and I have not been able to get through the Invalid parameter number. I have cut back code and options just trying to get two data into the MySQL 5.1 db using PHP 5.2 
I get a connection to the db fine and based on echo statements I feel confident that I am getting to the prepare statement ok.

The full code is below

```
 $DBHandle= new PDO('mysql:localhost;dbname=nameishere','userishere','passishere');

//* $DBHandle->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); --for USE
//* below is what I am currently using for debugging

$DBHandle->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );

//*next bit is to insure that if connection is lost database is not partially updated-I think- right now commented out
//* $DBHandle->beginTransaction();


    $mainIncrement= NULL;
    $firstnameOBS= $_POST['touristfirstname'];
    $todaysdateOBS= $_POST['touristdatetoday'];
    //*$picturenow= $_POST['picturesubmitted'];

    $JSONfirstname = json_encode($firstnameOBS);
    $JSONtodaysdate = json_encode($todaysdateOBS);
    //*$JSONpicturenow = json_encode($picturenow);

    echo ($JSONfirstname);


    $senditin = $DBHandle->prepare("INSERT INTO 'fkarnd'('firstname','datetoday') VALUES(:field1,:field2)", array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));

    $senditin->bindValue(':firstname', $JSONfirstname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $senditin->bindValue(':datetoday', $JSONtodaysdate, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    //* $myinputarray = array('firstname'=> $JSONfirstname, 'datetoday' => $JSONtodaysdate );

    $senditin->execute();


    //* commit allows transaction begun to complete
    //* $DBHandle->commit();



  //*  catch ( PDOException $e ) 
     echo "I'm sorry, I can't do that Dave......";
  //*file_put_contents( 'dbErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(),FILE_APPEND);  


  //*  echo "successful submission for the preservation of JohnsPass";
    $DBHandle = null;
```

I have tried putting the data in an array then executing, I have tried several different formats for the prepare statement including `INPUT ()INTO table WHERE()...`. I have tried having no binding. I really am just trying to put data into the db from an HTML5 form I created. The form data comes over ok based on echo statments and most of the PHP examples seem to deal with  SELECT not INPUT.

Below is the output and the error I cannot figure out

```
"Dread"
Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in /home/mabelsbi/public_html/johnspass.org/Science/FirstTry.php on line 46

Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number in /home/mabelsbi/public_html/johnspass.org/Science/FirstTry.php on line 46
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$senditin = $DBHandle->prepare("INSERT INTO 'fkarnd'('firstname','datetoday') VALUES(:field1,:field2)", array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));

$senditin->bindValue(':firstname', $JSONfirstname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$senditin->bindValue(':datetoday', $JSONtodaysdate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

You're using `:field1` and `:field2` in your query, and then setting `:firstname` and `:datetoday` as parameters; you just need to be consistent in what you're setting:

```
$senditin = $DBHandle->prepare("INSERT INTO `fkarnd` (`firstname`,`datetoday`) VALUES(:firstname,:datetoday)", array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));

$senditin->bindValue(':firstname', $JSONfirstname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$senditin->bindValue(':datetoday', $JSONtodaysdate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

(Edited to use backticks in SQL around field and table names)

Comment: Thanks but that seems to give a syntax error ?   which is this "Dread"
Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''fkarnd'('firstname','datetoday') VALUES('\"Dread\"','\"2012-10-25\"')' at line 1 in /home/mabelsbi/public_html/johnspass.org/Science/FirstTry.php on line 46
I'm sorry, I can't do that Dave......

Comment: I'll tweak the answer - you need to use backticks to quote field and table names

Comment: Let me hopefully bring humor into your day - I don't know what a backtick is .... OK of course I just researched it as I could not find it on my keyboard.... newby?  --- at anyrate that has solved the problem which I was asking THANKS A BUNCH - now of course I get an error which states -Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected in /home/mabelsbi/public_html/johnspass.org/Science/FirstTry.php on line 46
so the execute statement still is not happy... In any case thanks so much.

Comment: That sounds like you're not selecting a database when you create your database connection initially.

Comment: That's what I think, I have checked the database names in MySQL and I have tried backticks now in the PDO new request (it wants single quotes I believe) It does not kick out any error messages until it gets to the execute statement as the echo of firstname is what precedes the error message    ---- the relevant code i think is $DBHandle = new PDO('mysql:localhost;dbname=dbabi_Obs'  --should I have something other than localhost is there a format problem with dbabi_Obs - this is how the PHP myAdmin lists it... Thanks a bunch

Comment: If you want to test that the database connection works, try connecting using those parameters from the command line (`mysql -h hostname -D databasename -u username -p`, from memory - it'll prompt you for the password); that should let you see if the connection is working, at least

Comment: UPDATE - to get around the 1046 Problem I found that a working format for the Prepare statement requires not only the table name as much of the documentation seems to suggest but also the database name for example I was using `mytablename` in the insert into but I should have been using `mydatabase`.`mytablename` or at least this fixed the problem. also My server is running PHP 5.2  this may not be the same with PHP5.3 who knows...